# cascading relationships in icCube

Tags: iccube

Is it possible to manage a cascading relationship in icCube? For example, if I have the following 3 tables:
(1) NameID, FuelID
(2) FuelID, ScheduleID
(3) ScheduleID, DateTime, Value

Can I tie the NameID from table (1) to Value in table (3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using a Javascript View. You can check the documentation [here](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/user_guide/schemas_cubes/etl_javascript2.php) how to do this, the idea is that the 'main' table is the big one and the small ones, that should behave as lookup tables, are the 'cached' tables.

hope it helps